# How to include files for virtual methods?

Tags: c++, include, virtual

I have two class hierarchies: `A`s and `B`s. `A`s have a virtual method return `B`s, and `B`s have a virtual method return `A`s.

A.h

```
#pragma once
class B;

struct A
{
    virtual B* f() = 0;
};
```

A1.h

```
#pragma once
#include "A.h"
#include "B1.h"

struct A1 : public A
{
    B1* f() override;
};
```

B.h

```
#pragma once
class A;

struct B
{
    virtual A* g() = 0;
};
```

B1.h

```
#pragma once
#include "B.h"
#include "A1.h"

struct B1 : public B
{
    A1* g() override;
};
```

It doesn't compile with errors in VS2015

```
overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from A
```

With class forward declaration

```
class A1 : public A;
```

it should work. But C++ doesn't support such class forward declaration. How to fix it?

Comment: Include Guards.  Research "Include Guards".  They are tiny nanobots that are embedded into header files to prevent circular dependencies; or you can use your own definition. :-)

Comment: Don't they teach "the dance of the ifdefs" anymore? Or do we all now use these new fangled pragmas?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Just forget writing the include guards. With the include guards, the problem exists also.

Comment: Seems I didn't describe the question clearly and nobody got the true problem.

Comment: @user1899020 Perhaps include the actual error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with circular references, use forward declarations instead of `#include` statements where appropriate.

Also, the header files themselves should have guards in them to avoid declaring their content multiple times when `#include`'d multiple times.  The guards themselves can use either an `#ifndef`/`#define` pair, or a `#pragma once`, depending on your compiler.

---

A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

struct B;

struct A
{
    virtual B* f() = 0;
};

#endif
```

Or:

```
#pragma once

struct B;

struct A
{
    virtual B* f() = 0;
};
```

---

A1.h:

```
#ifndef A1_H
#define A1_H

#include "A.h"

struct B1;

struct A1 : public A
{
    B1* f() override;
};

#endif
```

Or:

```
#pragma once

#include "A.h"

struct B1;

struct A1 : public A
{
    B1* f() override;
};
```

---

A2.h

```
#ifndef A2_H
#define A2_H

#include "A.h"

struct B2;

struct A2 : public A
{
    B2* f() override;
};

#endif
```

Or:

```
#pragma once

#include "A.h"

struct B2;

struct A2 : public A
{
    B2* f() override;
};
```

---

B.h

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

struct A;

struct B
{
    virtual A* g() = 0;
};

#endif
```

Or:

```
#pragma once

struct A;

struct B
{
    virtual A* g() = 0;
};
```

---

B1.h

```
#ifndef B1_H
#define B1_H

#include "B.h"

struct A1;

struct B1 : public B
{
    A1* g() override;
};

#endif
```

Or:

```
#pragma once

#include "B.h"

struct A1;

struct B1 : public B
{
    A1* g() override;
};
```

---

B2.h

```
#ifndef B2_H
#define B2_H

#include "B.h"

struct A2;

struct B2
{
    A2* g() override;
};

#endif
```

Or

```
#pragma once

#include "B.h"

struct A2;

struct B2
{
    A2* g() override;
};
```

---

The `#include` statements to satisfy the forward-declared classes should be used in the method implementation source files, not in their declaring header files:

A1.cpp:

```
#include "A1.h"
#include "B1.h" // <--

B1* A1::f()
{
    return new B1; // or wherever the B1 object comes from...
}
```

A2.h

```
#include "A2.h"
#include "B2.h" // <--

B2* A2::f()
{
    return new B2; // or wherever the B2 object comes from...
}
```

B1.cpp

```
#include "B1.h"
#include "A1.h" // <--

A1* B1::g()
{
    return new A1; // or wherever the A1 object comes from...
}
```

B2.cpp

```
#include "B2.h"
#include "A2.h" // <--

A2* B2::g()
{
    return new A2; // or wherever the A2 object comes from...
}
```

---

That being said, forward declaring the structs is the only way to deal with circular references.  But since you can't forward declare hierarchies, I don't think there is a solution to your problem without rethinking your design.  If that is not an option, you will have to stay way from using covariant return values.

A.h

```
#pragma once

struct B;

struct A
{
    virtual B* f() = 0;
};
```

A1.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "A.h"

struct A1 : public A
{
    B* f() override;
};
```

A2.h

```
#pragma once

#include "A.h"

struct A2 : public A
{
    B* f() override;
};
```

B.h

```
#pragma once

struct A;

struct B
{
    virtual A* g() = 0;
};
```

B1.h

```
#pragma once

#include "B.h"

struct B1 : public B
{
    A* g() override;
};
```

B2.h

```
#pragma once

#include "B.h"

struct B2
{
    A* g() override;
};
```

A1.cpp:

```
#include "A1.h"
#include "B1.h" // <--

B* A1::f()
{
    return new B1; // or wherever the B1 object comes from...
}
```

A2.h

```
#include "A2.h"
#include "B2.h" // <--

B* A2::f()
{
    return new B2; // or wherever the B2 object comes from...
}
```

B1.cpp

```
#include "B1.h"
#include "A1.h" // <--

A* B1::g()
{
    return new A1; // or wherever the A1 object comes from...
}
```

B2.cpp

```
#include "B2.h"
#include "A2.h" // <--

A* B2::g()
{
    return new A2; // or wherever the A2 object comes from...
}
```

It just means you will have to use type-casts wherever you were relying on covariance when calling `f()` and `g()`.

Comment: Are you sure this works? In A1.h, the class forward B1 doesn't tell B1 is a derived class of B. That is my point.

Comment: @user1899020: covariant return types does not work in all compilers, either.

Comment: covariant return types are supported in VS2015. But this one is more complex. even don't know if it is covariant.

Comment: I currently drop one covariant return type.